# Can't match the fSpy reference distance on the object in Blender

Tags: fspy

I'm trying to replicate this object from a photo by matching the perspective with fSpy:
[image]

I had a lot of problem trying to precisely matching the perspective with axis.

I always got this problem:
[image]

If I align the Z axis with the pink segments, the brown ones are out of perspective and viceversa, if I align Z to the brown segments, the pink ones are out of perspective.

I realized that maybe is impossible to be 100% perfect and will alqays be some mm out of perspective.

However I tried to do my best and I think I reached a good result matching the perspective.

But when I import the .fSpy file on Blender, I can't match on the oobject the reference distance setted on fSpy (500 mm). Real dimensions of the object: (LWH): 50x29x24cm

[image]

Here is the .Blend file where there's the selected segments (the same of the image above) that should be 500mm: https://pasteall.org/blend/b17e214bb3a640f9a209667c682ec933

Can you guys help me understand what's wrong and solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know the size of the segment is 500mm can't you just scale it once in Blender to match the real size?

Comment: fSpy doesn't alway allwo to find the good dimensions, as Luciano says, if you know the real sizes, use them to create your object, then you can still use the camera to make the parts match the image as much as possible

Comment: If I build the model based on the fSpy file imported in Blender, no matter what measure in comes out.
Then build a second model/cube with the right measures and scale the first model to match the measures of the second one?

Comment: @moonboots
Could this way be right?

Comment: I would make the best as possible with fSpy, import, build a cube that has the good dimensions, put it over the image and begin modelling

Comment: @moonboots But If I put the cube over the image the dimensions don't match. I should scale the imported image but I can't with the simple S comand.
However I started a new file in fSpy because for me is very hard to match all the perspective, there's always an edge that doesn't match even if I follow everything as precisely as I can

Answer (score 1):

This image has a 3-point perspective. This is the simplest case for fSpy because you don't have to care about the principal point nor the focal length.

1/ set Number of vanishing points to 2

2/ set Principal Point to „from 3rd vanishing point”

3/ align 3 pairs of lines with the image - choose lines near the edges (in your case for the vertical axis choose one pink and one brown)

4/ drag the origin onto one of the corners of your object and set the reference distance

And now keep in mind that you have to be careful in Blender when you model - it's not enough to match your mesh with the reference image, because you don't know the distance from the camera.
I can't understand why most of the tutorials don't care about it. When you follow them - you'll never get the proper dimensions.

Remember to start from the origin you chose in fSpy. Add a plane there, set its Z position to 0 and align its edges with the image by moving them along the X and Y axis (without changing their Z coordinate)

As soon as you have this plane aligned properly extrude the edges along Z to model the exterior faces.

You can see the whole workflow in my tutorial:

https://youtu.be/daiMOYR8GS8